# Convert date in VARCHAR column (custom format) to DATE type in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

In my MS SQL Server 2008 database, I have the table with VARCHAR column which stores date formatted as YYMMDD. I'd like to cast/convert it to DATE data type in SELECT query. How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the Convert function?

```
DECLARE @DateString as varchar(6) ='120326'
SELECT CONVERT(Datetime, @DateString, 12)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @date varchar(8)='140507'
SELECT @date,CAST(@date AS date)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select Convert(datetime, Convert(Varchar(6),'140831'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET DATEFORMAT ymd
GO
select cast(columnName as DATE) FROM tableName
GO
```

You can check for invalid varchar values for date using [**ISDATE()**](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx) function